# How to create upgrade package using iceberg for mac

Tags: macos, installation, package, upgrade, osx-mavericks

I have created a installation package for mac os x using iceberg, which was successful and working fine.
But i have many version of my application.

So **My question is how to make a upgrade package using iceberg?,**

During upgrade some of the directories inside the installation directory should be untouched(not to be replaced)

Answer (score 0):

In your installer, leave out the directories which shouldn't be touched and they will be ignored. I've noticed that existing directories and files not targeted with changed/added bits aren't touched.

Comment: This could be the start of an answer if you could elaborate more on it and provide samples, commands to be used etc..